# Get full path of formula to open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula in cell A1 that refers to another open workbook:

```
=[book1.xlsb]Sheet1!$A$1
```

If I now use `Cells(1,1).Formula` I get exactly this formula.

If I close the workbook, this formula changes to:

```
='C:\\path\\[book1.xlsb]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

and I get this formula using the `Cells(1,1).Formula`.

Is there a way to get the "full path" of this formula (as if the other workbook was closed) while the workbook is still open?

I want to store these formulas as text, and change them back to formulas at a later time. If the workbook is closed at that time, the conversion back will not work.

Comment: You can return the Path to the workbook with `Workbooks("book1.xlsb").Path`.  Then use string functions to replace the workbook name with the full path. Note that in order for the workbook to have a path, it must have been saved (at least) once.

Comment: If you add a `'` at start of formula, it will become text instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return the full path of the workbook referenced in the formula of the cell passed to it.

```
Public Function GetFUllPath(r As Range) As String
Dim S As String
Dim str_filename
Dim fullpath As String
S = r.Formula
Select Case Mid(S, 3, 1)
     Case ":", "\"   'already has full path
     S = Left(S, InStr(S, "[") - 1) 'so just deduct rest of formula
     S = Replace(S, "=", "") 'strip out =
     fullpath = S
Case Else
    S = Mid(S, InStr(S, "[") + 1, InStr(S, "]") - InStr(S, "[") - 2) 'pull workbook name from inside []
    If InStr(S, ".") > 0 Then S = Left(S, InStr(S, ".") - 1)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        str_filename = wb.Name
                str_filename = Left(str_filename, InStr(str_filename, ".") - 1) 'no file extension ?
        If str_filename = S Then

            fullpath = wb.Path
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb
End Select
GetFUllPath = fullpath
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by:

1) closing the second book, so the full path is shown,

2) then doing a find/replace and replacing all the "=" with "xyxy"

3) now you have all the info you need as text so you can copy it etc at will - remove xyxy as necessary,

4) use find/replace to replace "xyxy" with "=" to make the original work again.